# Why does tracking a range object in a loop cause an error?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am writing a script in Script Lab for Microsoft Word. My goal is to search the document for a string, insert a comment on each range containing that string, and then track the range so that I can remove the comment later.

When I use `rangeCollection.getFirstOrNullObject()` to get the range and track it the script works fine, but when I try looping through `rangeCollection.items` I see the error below.

I've put together a minimal reproduction example which you can import into Script Lab. Here's the link: https://gist.github.com/abusch419/357e06a8c2fda077a06be2be0885cfb2

```
c {name: "RichApi.Error", code: "GeneralException", traceMessages: Array[0], innerError: null, debugInfo: Object…}
 name: "RichApi.Error"
 code: "GeneralException"
 traceMessages: Array[0]
 innerError: null
▶debugInfo: Object
 code: "GeneralException"
 message: "GeneralException"
 toString: function ()
 errorLocation: "Document._GetObjectByReferenceId"
 statement: "var v=context.root._getObjectByReferenceId("r!00000301") /* originally getItem(...) */;"
▶surroundingStatements: Array[5]
 0: "// >>>>>"
 1: "var v=context.root._getObjectByReferenceId("r!00000301") /* originally getItem(...) */;"
 2: "// <<<<<"
 3: "var insertOoxml=v.insertOoxml(...);"
 4: "// Instantiate {insertOoxml}"
▶fullStatements: Array[3]
 line: 24
 column: 243947
 sourceURL: "https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-mac-16.00.js"
```

Here's my code for tracking the ranges using getFirstOrNullObject() instead of a loop. This works:

```js
async function insertFirstComment(context) {
  const rangeCollection = context.document.body.search(searchQuery);
  rangeCollection.load("length");

  await context.sync();

  const range = rangeCollection.getFirstOrNullObject();
  range.insertOoxml(commentOoxml, "Replace");
  range.track();
  ranges.push(range);

  await context.sync();
}
```

Here's my code for tracking the ranges in a loop. It triggers an error when trying to remove the comments. The error is thrown when we sync after removing comments from the tracked ranges.

```js
async function insertCommentsInLoop(context) {
  const rangeCollection = context.document.body.search(searchQuery);
  rangeCollection.load("length");

  await context.sync();

  for (const range of rangeCollection.items) {
    range.insertOoxml(commentOoxml, "Replace");
    range.track();
    ranges.push(range);
  }

  await context.sync();
}
```

And here's my code for removing comments:

```js
async function removeComments(context) {
  for (const range of ranges) {
    range.insertOoxml(ooxmlWithoutComment, "Replace");
    range.untrack();
  }

  await context.sync();
  ranges = [];
}
```

## Edit 1: Updated `getFirstOrNullObject` call

Rick Kirkham helpfully pointed out that I was not using getFirstOrNullObject correctly, so I updated the implementation. 
I have also updated the gist with the Script Lab snippet:

https://gist.github.com/abusch419/357e06a8c2fda077a06be2be0885cfb2

The function using getFirstOrNullObject was working correctly to begin with, and the updated version still works. The version with the loop still throws the error above.

Here is the updated version:

```js
async function insertFirstComment(context) {
  const rangeCollection = context.document.body.search(searchQuery);
  rangeCollection.load('length');

  await context.sync();

  const range = rangeCollection.getFirstOrNullObject();
  range.load('isNullObject')

  await context.sync();

  if (!range.isNullObject) {
    range.insertOoxml(commentOoxml, "Replace");
    range.track();
    ranges.push(range);

    await context.sync();
  } else {
    console.log(`Did not find ${searchQuery} in the document`)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix the problem, but you are not using the `getFirstOrNullObject` method correctly. See [orNullObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-advanced-concepts#ornullobject-methods) for details. Fix that and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful feedback, Rick. I have updated my code to use `getFirstOrNullObject` correctly, but I am still seeing the error.

Comment: I'm trying to get some help internally at Microsoft.

Comment: @abusch419 Please raise this as a probable bug on [the issues for the office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose). Provide enough code to reproduce. For example, I don't see where the ranges array is declared.